# Counting matches against a keyword database?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is an attempt at sorting unknown files into unknown directories by listing each directory's content into a list (placed in each directory). A single new file `%filename%` is divided into words (by spaces) and those words are used to search the file databases `keywords.txt` in each directory. I am supposed to count these hits together to figure out where the file belongs, but my counting system does not work at all.

```
set "count="
:: feed a list of all subdirectories
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d') do (
    rem reset keywords, then rebuild 
    echo. >"%%~i\keywords.txt" & for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%%~i\*.*" /b /a:-d') do echo %%~na >>"%%~i\keywords.txt"
    @echo on
    for %%a in (%filename%) do find /i /c "%%a" "%%~i\keywords.txt" && set count+=1
    @echo off
    echo count is %count%
)
```

one clue might be that the last line produces no `%count%`, just `count is`

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in (%filename%) do find /i /c "%%a" "%%~i\keywords.txt" && set /A count+=1
@echo off
CALL echo count is %%count%%
```

The `/A` in the `set` command invokes arithmetic mode; your code would have simply set the variable `count+` to the value `1`.

The `call` invokes a subshell which reports the required value. There must be *thousands* of SO articles on this issue. Try searching for `delayed expansion`.